# How to validate the APK signing certificate at client side?

Tags: android, security, certificate, client-server, apk

I am developing an android app which is talking with a server, and I want to verify at run time that my app has not been modified since I released it(a user with a modified app should not be able to login to app).

Since modified app's signature is different from the original signature, I decided to :

1. Extract signing certificate/s which is embedded in the android app
2. send it to the server with the login request (Coding the whole verification process in client side(i.e. apk) does not work as someone could modify the apk to bypass it.)
3. verify it
4. if certificate is valid process login request / else return error

This is my code for number 1 above :

```
Context context = this;
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
int flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;
PackageInfo packageInfo = null;

try {
    packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, flags);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
```

**So my questions are :**

1. Is there a better way to verify an apk?
2. If this method is okay,
   2.1 Would sending a certificate cost high in bandwidth?
   2.2 How can I verify the certificate?(I have mykey.jks at server side which I originally used to sign the apk)

(Also this is my first ever question on stackoverflow, so pointing out any mistakes I did in asking the question are highly appreciated!. )

Comment: either you can just check if your app. is downloaded from play-store or not. that's it.

Comment: That is also fine, but the issue is, it is wholly dependent on client side so it can be bypassed relatively easily. But it does not hurt to that level of a check as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it will always be possible for someone to bypass this kind of security, e.g. by hardcoding the certificates passed to your server. You can only try to make it as hard as possible but it will never be 100% secure.

That being said what you're doing seems ok. Note that `pm.signatures` is deprecated in favour of `pm.signingInfo` in the latest SDK.

Size wise, a certificate is not big, but to make the requests even smaller, you should probably only send a hash (e.g. SHA256).

To prevent people from hardcoding the certificate in the request, you could also consider hashing another value together with the certificate, i.e. hash(certificate + timestamp), and send also the timestamp in the request so you can recompute the hash server side. And if the timestamp is too far away from the current date, reject the request. Again, it's not perfectly secure, but adds another layer of complexity to reverse engineer your code. You could also add the versionCode and start rejecting requests of old versions (e.g. if you detect a security bug in one of your old versions) and prompt those users to update the app (or do it for them in the background and only prompt for the install, thanks to the new API Play provides).

As someone pointed out, your code could also check out that the install came from Play (`packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName()).equals("com.android.vending");`), but that information is easily spoofable so not sure it adds much security.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes, I was kind of looking for a perfect(at least an almost perfect) method. Guess I was being naive.
But anyway I guess it does not hurt to add multiple layers of security checks.
P.S. Thank you for the update on SDKs and APIs and also the timestamp method. I will certainly look in to that.

Comment: You can save the release timestamp on server before release

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Pierre the way you perform the check is a valid one but I would like to alert for the fact that certificate pinning can be bypassed at run time, with instrumentation frameworks like [Frida](https://www.frida.re/) or [xPosed](http://repo.xposed.info/), but is still advisable and encouraged to use it as one more security layer. For more insights on this please give a quick read to [this article](http://blog.approov.io/the-problem-with-pinning) to understand how pinning is easy to implement, how it can be a nightmare to maintain from the operational point of view and how it can be bypassed.

> Is there a better way to verify an apk?

Yes it exists and is called Mobile App Attestation. This solution will consist of a SDK integrated in the mobile app that communicates with a cloud service on the background, thus with no impact on the user experience.

The Mobile App Attestation solution guarantees at run-time that an app is not being man in the middle attacked, being tampered with, not running in a rooted or jail broken device, not attached to a debugger, not running on an emulator and that is the same original one uploaded into the app store or google play store.

So the cloud service on successful attestation of the mobile app integrity issues a very short lived [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) that is signed with a secret only known by the API server and by the Mobile App Attestation service running in the cloud. On an attestation failure the JWT is signed with a secret not known by the API server. In each request to the API server the mobile app will send this JWT token and the API server will verify that the signature is valid and the token have not expired and will refuse the request when it fails any of the verifications.

Once the secret used by the cloud attestation service is not known by the mobile app it is not possible to reverse engineer the JWT token, even when the mobile app is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

You can find such a service in [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html)(I work here), that have SDKs for several platforms, including Android. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Dynamic instrumentation toolkit for developers, reverse-engineers, and security researchers.

[xPosed](http://repo.xposed.info/)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs.

[JWT Token](https://jwt.io/)

> Token Based Authentication
>
> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

Comment: Actually I work in the cyber security field and when I was researching for mobile app related security, I came across Approov. To be honest, I did not fully understand how it works and how it differentiates from usual (previously mentioned) methods.  
If you could publish answers to questions such as  
- How it checks integrity of the app  
-how the rooted/integrity checks cannot be bypassed  
That would be great.

Comment: We don't perform checks in the sense we make decisions in the device, we take several measurements that we sent back to the cloud service to decide if it issues a valid signed token and this tokens are impossible to reverse engineer in the sense of determining if they are valid or invalid and in the sense of faking them. As you may understand we cannot go into much detail, once this is the secret sauce of our receipt, but for our clients we can disclose more info under a Non Disclosure Agreement. Please feel free to contact us directly or to post a question in Stackoverflow tagged #approov.

Comment: yes, I totally understand. Thank you for the information. I will certainly keep in touch with #approov.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. See you soon.

Comment: But wait, you used an article about certificate pinning for network connection as an argument in discussion about checking app's signing certificates? App signing certificate is not something that you rotate on regular basis like the server certificates, you are mixing concepts which sounds similar but are different things.